# i have made a discord bot my ban commands works but my kick command is not working

Tags: discord.js

```js
const { getUserFromMention } = require("../userinfo/getuser.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "kick a player",
    execute(message, client) {
        const split = message.content.split(/ +/);
        const args = split.slice(1);

        const member = getUserFromMention(args[0], client);

        if (!member) {
            return message.reply("Say the name lets dew it !");
        }

        if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.reply("I can't kick this user.");
        }

        return message.guild.members
            .kick(member)
            .then(() => message.reply(`${member.username} was kicked.`))
            .catch((error) => message.reply("They are above my paygrade"));
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the kick function in the member object itself

Try this

```js
return member.kick()
  .then(() => message.reply(`${member.user.username} was kicked.`))
  .catch(error => message.reply('They are above my paygrade'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
const { getUserFromMention } = require("../userinfo/getuser.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "kick a player",
    execute(message, client) {
        const split = message.content.split(/ +/);
        const args = split.slice(1);

        const member = getUserFromMention(args[0], client);

        if (!member) {
            return message.reply("Say the name lets dew it !");
        }

        if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.reply("I can't kick this user.");
        }

       return member.kick()
       .then(() => message.reply(`${member.user.username} was kicked.`))
       .catch(error => message.reply('They are above my paygrade'));
     },
};
```